Creating Internal Loops Dynamically
My code is working perfectly :
const i=['a','e','i','o','u'];
let q=[];

for(let t=0,l=i.length;t<l;++t)
{
    for(let e=t+1,l=i.length;e<l;++e)
    {
        for(let z=e+1,l=i.length;z<l;++z)
        {
            q.push([i[z],i[e],i[t]]);
        }
    }
}

console.table(q);

But my goal is to make the internal loops dynamically so I could modify the number on the internal loops (3 at that specific case).
For example if I would want to modify the internal loops to 4 I would need to rewrite the code as such:
const i=['a','e','i','o','u'];
let q=[];

for(let t=0,l=i.length;t<l;++t)
{
  for(let e=t+1,l=i.length;e<l;++e)
  {
    for(let z=e+1,l=i.length;z<l;++z)
    {
      for(let c=z+1,l=i.length;c<l;++c)
      {
        q.push([i[c],i[z],i[e],i[t]]);
      }
    }
  }
}

console.table(q);

Therefore, I want to be able to make the internal loops DYNAMICALLY with the same exact formula.

“Dynamically creating loops” is the wrong approach; you want to find an algorithm that produces an equivalent result. It’d help if you specified what exactly you’re trying to do.

Very much an X/Y problem

@deceze The formula is already presented here and the "Dynamically creating loops” IS the formula. All I need is to be able to recreate the same exact formula dynamically instead of rewrite the code for a specific number of loops.

This is something similar to but not quite like a cartesian product of multiple arrays. Which can be solved without dynamically creating loops: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12303989/476

You're starting with an array of vowels (called i). Can you describe, in words, what you're trying to produce from that? It would help others to help you find an appropriate solution to your problem.

This is where you can use recursion. This means you have a function that takes care of creating subarrays of a given size, but relies on the following observation:
If we can do the job for subarrays which are one item shorter than the given size, then we can do it also for the given size: we just execute the function to generate the arrays that are one item shorter, and then append to each the "current" element.
Here is a recursive implementation that outputs the same table as your example:


function getSubarrays(arr, depth, take=0) {
    if (depth <= 0) return [[]]; // One result: an empty subarray
    depth--;
    const subarrays = [];
    for (let i = take; i < arr.length - depth; i++) {
        for (const subarray of getSubarrays(arr, depth, i + 1)) {
            subarrays.push([...subarray, arr[i]]);
        }
    }
    return subarrays;
}

const arr = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
const results = getSubarrays(arr, 3);
// Output with console.log
for (const row of results) console.log(...row);



So the second argument given to getSubarrays is the number of nested loops you want to execute. This argument is decreased one step at a time in recursion.

Thank you soooooooooooooooo much @trincot that is *E-X-A-C-T-L-Y what I was looking for!!!
